# How is null represented in .NET

Tags: .net, memory, null

I was having a conversation with a co-worker and the subject of null came up. He was telling me that in .NET behind the scenes it is just a really small number. I always thought that the object just didn't have a pointer to any memory on the heap but i wasn't sure either way.

So i'm hoping the community can clear it up for us ;P

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a nullable type instance is set to null, its underlying value is zero.

To be more specific, a nullable type is a structure that combines a value of the underlying type together with a boolean null indicator. An instance of a nullable type has two public read-only properties: **HasValue** of type bool, and **Value** of the nullable type’s underlying type.

**HasValue** is true for a non-null instance and false for a null instance.

So when **HasValue** is true, the **Value** property returns the contained value. When **HasValue** is false, an attempt to access the Value property throws an exception. But if you could access it, you would find it contains zero.

Comment: This is all about `Nullable<T>` - it's *not* about null references.

Comment: @Jon, are you saying that my use of the word "instance" is imprecise?

Comment: I'm saying that your whole answer is talking about nullable value types, whereas the question just talks about "null" which could be about nullable value types *or* just the null value for references. It actually looks like it's *more* about null references than nullable value types, but it's hard to say for sure.

Answer (score 18):

It's 0.

Snip from ldnull in ECMA-335 spec:

> It might be thought that ldnull is
>   redundant: why not use ldc.i4.0 or
>   ldc.i8.0 instead? The answer is that
>   ldnull provides a size-agnostic null –
>   analogous to an ldc.i instruction,
>   which does not exist. However, even if
>   CIL were to include an ldc.i
>   instruction it would still benefit
>   verification algorithms to retain the
>   ldnull instruction because it makes
>   type tracking easier.

Comment: I really have to disagree that null is 0... 0 is a value... null is a placeholder for the absence of a reference to an object. To initialize an object to be null and then say "oh, it's also equal to the value 0" is a little contradictory in my opinion

Comment: @lomaxx - it really is zero; that's the way it's implemented at CIL level. You can think of it as being a special memory address which is interpreted as null.

Comment: @lomaxx: null is definitely a value. You can do everything with it that you can with another value - pass it, assign it to a variable etc. Its *bitwise representation* is all zeroes.

Answer (score 0):

from my experience, I believe `Nothing` will work, and so will `DBNull.Value`

Comment: ...And I just completely misunderstood it.  I believe Null or 'Nothing' is numerically equivalent to Zero, and stored as whatever data type the variable it is assigned to it

Comment: Probably best just to delete the answer, else you will get down votes  :)  +1 for honesty

Comment: And now you see the difference between == and ===, try comparing these various null types.

Answer (score -2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edakx9da.aspx):

> The null keyword is a literal that
>   represents a null reference, one that
>   does not refer to any object

To try and make it a little clearer in the older versions of c#, a value type couldn't be null, ie, it HAD to have a value, if you didn't assign one, you got a potentially random value so something like:

```
int i;
i++;
console.writeline(i);
```

in the older versions of c# objects had to be initialized otherwise they were null, which meant they had no reference to any object.

Now with nullable value types in c# 2.0+ you can have a nullable int which means that if you have this code:

```
int? i;
i++;
console.writeline(i);
```

you will actually get an exception at i++ because i has never been initialized to anything other than null. If null was 0, this code would execute fine because it'd just evaluate to 0+1, however this is incorrect behaviour.

If null was always 0 and you had a a nullable int, and you wrote some code like:

```
int? i;
if (int == 0)
{
//do something
}
```

there is a very real possibility you could get some unexpected behaviour IF null was the same as 0 because there is no way the compiler could differentiate between the int being null and the int being explicitly set to 0.

Another example that clarifies things in my mind:

```
public int? AddNumbers(int? x, int? y)
{
    if (x == null || y == null)
        return null;
    if (x == 0)
        return y;
    if (y == 0)
        return x;

    return x + y;
}
```

in this example, it's clear that null and 0 are very different because if you were to pass in 0 for x or y, and null was equal to 0, then the code above would never get to the checks for x == 0 or y == 0, however if you run the code and pass in 0 for x or y, the checks do get executed.

Comment: I don't think this helps. The behaviour of lifted operators has little to do with the underlying value of null. And as it happens, the binary value of a "null" Nullable<T> *is* zero. All zeros. So for int? it is 5 zeros (one for the bool flag, 4 for the int).

Comment: (note, the -1 isn't from me; I prefer to feed back via comments - not just down-vote blindly)

Comment: but if the value of null *is* zero, then what is the value of zero? how do you differentiate between the two?

Comment: Nullable<T> is treated specially by both the CLR and the C# language to make it appear that it is a true null. It isn't really; it's just a compiler trick that lets you write "x == null" rather than "!x.HasValue", because Nullable<T> is a value type itself so can't really be null.

Comment: lomaxx, a nullable type is a structure that combines a value of the underlying type with a boolean null indicator. If the type is set to a value of null, that means its underlying value is zero and its null indicator is set to true.

Comment: RoadWarrior... that's probably the best explanation of "How is null represented".

Comment: I guess there's 3 ways of asking this question: What is the underlying value of null? What is the (face) value of null? and What structure is used to represent null? I was trying to answer the second where as others were trying to answer other variations so that's probably where the confusion arose